# jQuery selector for other attributes than id doesn't work in the same way

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a HTML page, if I type in my console `$("#title")[0]`, I get:

```
<div id="title" class="ms-font-xxl ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semilight">Change Case</div>
```

Ok. If I type `$("#title")[0].id`, I get `"title"`.

The problem is when I type `$("#title")[0].class`, I get `undefined`.

Shouldn't I get `ms-font-xxl ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semilight`? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two way of getting it:

Before jQuery 1.6, use `.attr()`
After jQuery 1.6+, use `.prop()`

1. jQuery method `.prop()`: `$('#title').prop('class')`
2. JS method `.className`:  `$('#title')[0].className`

#### Since you are using jQuery, just go 1st option =D

> #### `.prop`
>
> REF: http://api.jquery.com/prop/
>
> #### `Element.className`
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

```js
console.log($('#title').prop('class'));
console.log($('#title')[0].className);

//get array of class name
console.log($('#title')[0].className.split(/\s+/));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="title" class="ms-font-xxl ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semilight">Change Case</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is something I don't get. Why `$('#title').prop('class')` works, but `$('#title')[0].prop('class')` doesn't work?
`$('#title')` returns an array, so we should access an element of the array before trying to access its property through `prop("class")`, shouldn't we?

Comment: @FelipeCostaGualberto id are unique for each page so `$('#title')` will only ever return 1 result.

Comment: @FelipeCostaGualberto if you print out `$('#title')[0]` it is the raw HTML, with the native JS method `.className` you will get the class name too but that's kind hack

Comment: Now I understand, I agree. Maybe not a good practice because it would mix JS with jQuery.

Comment: @FelipeCostaGualberto take a look at this `console.log($('#title'));` there are so many method jQuery added, and the `[0]` is the raw HTML

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#title').attr('class')
```

Not all the attributes could be grabbed instantly